# Sorting list by filename

Tags: python, list, sorting

I read in the filenames of some images which are stored like this:

```
(path/to/images/1_1.png)
(path/to/images/1_2.png) ...
(path/to/images/10_1.png) ...
(path/to/images/1000_1.png)
```

When reading the filenames to a list with this code

```
import cv2
import glob

folders = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\tobis\OneDrive\Desktop\Masterarbeit\data\2017-IWT4S-CarsReId_LP-dataset\*')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.png'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)
```

The first image in my list is the one that's filename is `(path/to/images/1000_1.png)` instead of `(path/to/images/1_1.png)`. It is important to get the files in the right order because I need to match the images with another list. Is there a way to sort the list in the way I need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is known as natural sorting, as opposed to the default lexicographical sorting.

Here is an example that I think will suit your needs.

```
import re

def natural_sort(l):
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

fl = ['path/to/images/1000_1.png', 'path/to/images/1_1.png']

print(natural_sort(fl))
```

reference : [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

See this working example:

```
sorted(['path/to/images/1000_1.png',
        'path/to/images/1_1.png',
        'path/to/images/1_2.png',
        'path/to/images/10_1.png'
       ], 
        key=lambda x: int(x.split('/')[-1][:-4].replace('_','')))
```